# Add media edit gallery thumbnail resize dashboard

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I know it sounds like stupid but my client is asking for it and I have no idea how to get through it.

When I create a gallery in post by clicking "Add Media" and select images, then I hit the button that says "Create a new gallery". Now the next page is of ordering images where I can drag and drop the image to re-order. The problem is right now they are very big thumbnail(3 thumbnail per row). I need them to be more small(atleast 6 thumbnail per row).

Is it possible. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', function(){
    ?>
    <style>
    .attachment-preview {
        width: 90px !important;
        height: 90px !important;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
});
```

But you'll have to [*find your way to get the CSS right*](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index). This one is just a test, it works but have issues.

Comment: Above script has a syntax error. I was trying to fixed it but can't seem to be done.